# Chrome extension, unique id per install, for analytics

Tags: google-chrome-extension, analytics, mixpanel

I want to track events on a chrome extension I'm building. So I want to have a unique identifier for each user.

I don't want any information about the user, simply I want all of they're events grouped together.

Is there a good way to solve this, without pinging a server. Or will I just use a really long random string so the probability of getting the same string by another user is low.

I'm using segment.io's analytics.js package to integrate with mixpanel.

Comment: how did you manage to get this work, I am loading segment.io in my content script but it seems to only send page not tracks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why Mixpanel is tagged on this question, but since it is, I'll mention that the [Mixpanel jslib](https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.js) solves this problem.

If you send events without identifying the user, the jslib automatically generates a UUID based on time, `Math.random()`, and browser characteristics. This data is stored in a cookie.

Comment: I was going to use segmentio to send events to mixpanel, I should have specified.

Comment: What a noob I am to not think of using the current time to generate a unique id. I wont use mixpanels jslib, but you deserve the accepted answer nonetheless.

Comment: yes true, but using it as a seed for a 32 digit long random string will be okay for me

Comment: Using Math.random() is not guaranteed to be unique. It probably serves well enough for anonymous statistics, but if you are going to track across browser restarts, you should generate a unique id and then store it using chrome.storage. When starting up, you can check if it exists in storage and use that. There's a great implementation of RFC4122 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3):

You can generate an id upon extension install/update. You can then use this value as your unique id. Something like this should work (put it in your background page):

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(info){
    //    
    // info.reason should contain either "install" or "update"

    var sessionId = localStorage.getItem("session-id");

    if(!sessionId){
      localStorage.setItem("session-id", "random-session-id");
    }
});
```

More info on onInstalled is here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled. NB: it fires on install, extension update and Chrome update.

Comment: How can I test this feature during development?